# d:DataContext not working with MVVMCross and Windows Store app

Tags: windows-store-apps, mvvmcross, blend

- VS 2013
- Blend
- Windows Store App (8.1)
- **MVVMCross**

I want to set the design time DataContext of a Page in my Windows Store (8.1) app. I am doing this using d:DataContext.

**UPDATE**

<del>However this is being ignored at design time and I suspect this is an issue with MvvmCross</del>

If I remove the "d:" it works but then it is not restricted to design time. If I try it on a standard Page rather than an MvxStorePage the d: is respected and the datacontext is set at Design Time only.

I originally thought that the d: was causing the DataContext setting to be ignored because when I removed the d: it worked. However I have just tried

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=firsts:TipViewModel,
               IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
```

and that works so it cannot be simply be the 'd:' but a combination of 'd:' and my approach of

```
d:DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Factory}, 
Converter={StaticResource DesignConverter}, 
ConverterParameter=TipViewModel}"
```

I do not want to go direct to a DesignTime version of my VM instead I am using the approach in Nick's article [Coded Design Time Data using Mvvmcross](http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2014/03/20/Coded-Design-Time-Data-using-Mvvmcross-for-Windows-and-Windows-Phone.aspx) which lets me inject a DesignTime DataService into the exisiting VM

Has any got any ideas as to why my stuff is silently failing?

Thanks

Pat